# Regex for form validation

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, validation

hello I have a simple form to validate I already asked about a client side validation but the problem now is that server side validation isn't working the idea is to validate the input field and check if its length between [5-20] chars and display an error msg if not as well as preventing the form from submitting this should happen at the client side then if every thing is right the data should be sent to the server and the server will check if the input data contains just letters if yes then it will echo "thanks for submitting the form " and if not display the error message " the name should contain only letters from a to z" the problem is after the form being submitted and I get the ok from the client side validation I never get one of the server messages please help here is the code

```
 <?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $name = $_POST['user'];

    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
         echo "name must contain only characters";   
       else
         echo "thanks for submitting the form";


}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>form validation</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
       $( document ).ready(function() 
        {

                $("form").on('submit', myfunction); //<-- listen for form submit, not button click

                function myfunction(evt)
                { //<-- the event object is automatically passed along;
                  //    this is key for suppressing submission
                    name = $("#user").val();
                    nameError = $(".error").first();
                    myNameError = "";

                    if(name.length < 5 || name.length > 20)
                        myNameError += "length should be between 5 and 20 ";
                    else
                        myNameError += "ok"

                    if (myNameError) 
                    {
                        evt.preventDefault(); //<-- suppress submission if error found
                        nameError.html(myNameError);
                    }



                 }


        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .error
        {
            color : red;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">
        NAME : <input type="text" name="user" id="user"><span class="error"></span><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might be a stupid question but why do you have action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" ?

Comment: Your regex also matches spaces `/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/`

Comment: What happens when you process the form? You should form sentences in your question, it is a bit hard to read.

Comment: You know the form will be sent using 'POST', why don't you check if `isset($_POST['user'])` instead of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'`. Maybe your server doesn't allow `REQUEST_METHOD` directive in `$_SERVER`.

Comment: actually am reading the w3schools PHP lesson and this is how they do it if you got a better place to learn from that would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a problem:

```
if (name.length < 5 || name.length > 20)
    myNameError += "length should be between 5 and 20 ";
else
    myNameError += "ok"

if (myNameError) 
{
     ...
```

You are setting the `myNameError` variable to a string, either the error message or the string `ok`. So `if (myNameError)` is always `true` so you will never make any POST request to the server.

To solve this problem, you should not add any string to `myNameError` when there is no error.